# Calling a method on an object without knowing its class type

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm using Fragment in my android app. At the moment I have 2 fragments being displayed in split view style, lets call the Fragment A and Fragment B. Fragment B gets changed frequently and there are many different types of Fragment it could get changed to.

I'm looking to call a method on Fragment B. This method exists in most but not all of the types of Fragments that could be displayed.

Here is what I have:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag("ContentFrag");
if (frag != null) {
    if (frag.getClass().equals(ExampleFragment1.class))
        ((ExampleFragment1)frag).refresh();
    else if (frag.getClass().equals(ExampleFragment2.class))
        ((ExampleFragment2)frag).refresh();
    else if (frag.getClass().equals(ExampleFragment3.class))
        ((ExampleFragment3)frag).refresh();
}
```

And here is what I would like:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag("ContentFrag");
if (frag != null) {
    frag.refresh();
}
```

Is there any way of achieving this or will I have to write a load of if statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `Fragment`s implement for example a `Refreshable` interface and you can check for it.

```
if(frag instanceof Refreshable)
    ((Refreshable)frag).refresh();
}
```

This is not pretty but prettier than the above code.

Comment: Great minds think alike :P Seeing your answer made me realise I forgot the cast!

Comment: The main problem is that you can't reason with the android framework and as a last resort you have to do such ugly things like this. This is like the `Canvas`' `drawLine` method which is not remotely sensible compared to any vector drawing library which have a `moveTo` and a `lineTo` method most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

you could potentially use instanceof keyword to see if the fragment is an instance of one of these special fragments. Is this method that's only in some fragments something you made yourself or part of the API?

If it's one you made yourself have those fragments implement an interface called something like RefreshableFragment. This interface would contain said method, then all you have to do is:

```
if(frag!=null && frag instanceof RefreshableFragment)
    frag.refresh();
```

Comment: And I commented on your one saying I did as we answered practically the same time...

Comment: Oh I see. I did not notice :)

Answer (score 2):

the solution is to create a parent class named RefreshableFragment, that has refresh() method:

```
public class RefreshableFragment extends Fragment {

public void refresh();
}
```

all your fragment classes should extend this class:

```
public class ExampleFragment1 extends RefreshableFragment {

    public void refresh() {
       // implementation
    }

}
```

then you can use the refreshed fragment in your code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
RefreshableFragment frag = (RefreshableFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("ContentFrag");
if (frag != null) {
    frag.refresh();
}
```

Comment: `Fragment` is a class not an interface.